# Hang issue when executing a selenium script using mvn exec:java in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, maven, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

My selenium automation scripts that run on IE browser, developed using an in-house automation framework runs fine in Eclipse.

Now, I am building a tool (windows forms application) in .NET to launch these scripts from my tool. Below is the flow.

1. A windows service developed in .NET launches the tool.
2. The tool starts a new command prompt process providing the mvn exec: java command along with the required parameters as arguments.
3. The tool gets minimized.
4. Java, IEDriverserver processes start in the background
5. The script starts to run; IE browser is launched.

Till the point the browser is not launched, I can maximize and minimize my tool. However once the test starts running on the browser, if I try to restore my tool by clicking on the tab in the taskbar, nothing happens. And when I do this, sometimes, the browser also hangs (I am not sure if the IEDriverServer hangs  which in turn makes the browser to hang). Interesting point to note here is that the tool internally is still running, I see that from the logs. Its just the GUI window that does not respond.

When I run the tool standalone, I am able to switch between IE and the tool and also minimize and restore the tool from taskbar. But when this tool is invoked from the service it seems to behave differently. I cannot understand if the problem is in the way how the processes are launched or if its a threading issue or something else.

- IE version - IE 11
- IEDriverServer version - 2.47.0 - 64 bit.
- .NET framework version - 4.5

I have been struck on this for quite long. Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.